# Conflict with iPhone media queries. "X" Media Query overwriting "Y"

Tags: iphone, media-queries

The "X" media queries overwriting "Y" Eg.

```
  /* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */
    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){ 
    header{ height:480px; width: 100%; background-color: blue; } 
    h1:before {content: "iPhone 4";}
    }
    /* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */
    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px){
    header{ height:599px; width: 100%; background-color: blue; } 
    h1:before {content: "iPhone 5";}
    }
```

I tried adding the device-aspect-ratio to fix the issue, but did not work.

Somebody have the answer?

How avoid this situation on new devices in the future?

Answer (score 0):

The first query asks if the window width (in realtime) is between 320-480. So, if I load your page with a device that has a realtime window width of 400px – the query becomes true, thus the corresponding css will be applied.

However, if using the same device on the second query – that query will be true too because the 400-width-device fits also within the 320-568 span.

I don't know what scenario you want to accomplish but one way is to not try to target individual devices. Example: You could set unique css for the spans ..301-350, 351-400, 401-450... (and so on). That way, a single width fits in one span only. Also, new devices that enter the market will automatically "pick" one of the spans.

Comment: **@Håkan**, thanks for reply.  

Right now, I am using the way that you mention, creating ranges for apply css styles (320-359, 360-374, 375-413. 414-599, 600-767... and so on.) But I wanted to go further.  

According to "I don't know what scenario you want to accomplish" I want that the  height of the header and each section of the website be accurate based on each screen of the differents devices. Eg  
iPhone 4
header section{height:480px}
iPhone 5
header section{height:599px}  

Another way that I thought to do this would be to combine the width and height of the media query rules.